# No data returned with this WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

`select  distinct trunc(err_log_date),to_char(trunc(err_log_date),'DAY') from ERR_TAB ;`

The above statement returns dates with day as Friday. But when I use the same logic in where in clause, it is not returing any data. Why could it be ?

```
select * from ERR_TAB where to_char(trunc(err_log_date),'DAY')='FRIDAY';
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because Oracle puts spaces at the end -- at least to match the length of "Wednesday", but the exact length might depend on internationalization settings.

Just use `DY`:

```
where to_char(trunc(err_log_date), 'DY') = 'FRI';
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, include `FM` format element which returns a value with no leading or trailing blanks:

```
select * from ERR_TAB where to_char(trunc(err_log_date),'FMDAY')='FRIDAY';
                                                         --
                                                         This!
```

Comment: Littlefoot, Can you please share any documentation for the same. Amazing answer BTW.

Comment: Sure, @Ankit. It is about **Format models** in any Oracle database version's documentation (this is 11g): https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210

Answer (score 0):

Thank You both ! So I devised another option just to wrap around my original query with a trim and it worked. Given below.

```
select * from ERR_TAB where trim(to_char(trunc(err_log_date),'DAY'))='FRIDAY';
```